# Need help understanding project codes in Wikimedia pagecounts dumps (hourly num visits per page)

Tags: wikipedia

I need this understanding for legally scaping Wikipedia/Wikimedia from their so-called `pagecounts` dumps. While I am writing software, this is not a programming question. It is a question about the file format. I believe that my question does belong here but in case you believe it does not, please direct me to the right Stack Exchange site. Or to a mailing list or sommething similar.

The files are available here: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-ez/merged/

sample file that I looked at is: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-ez/merged/2019/2019-01/pagecounts-2019-01-01.bz2

It is pretty big - around 400 Mb when archived. If you were to unarchive (un-bz2) it, you would see this comment at the top of the file:

```
# Wikimedia page request counts for 01/01/2019 (dd/mm/yyyy)
#
# Each line shows 'project page daily-total hourly-counts'
#
# Project is 'language-code project-code'
#
# Project-code is
#
# b:wikibooks,
# k:wiktionary,
# n:wikinews,
# q:wikiquote,
# s:wikisource,
# v:wikiversity,
# wo:wikivoyage,
# z:wikipedia (z added by merge script: ...
```

For example the line 28 `aa.b MediaWiki:Ipb_already_blocked 3 B1M1X1` is meant to convey the following (unless I made a mistake): `language_code=aa, project_code=b:wikibooks, page=MediaWiki:Ipb_already_blocked, daily_total=3, 1-2AM=1, noon-1PM=1, 11PM-midnight=1`

However, the above description of the file format is incomplete. I counted all the project codes in this file and in addition to `b, n, q, s, v, wo and z` I encountered: `m, m.d, d, wd, m.m, m.s, m.q, m.b, voy, w, m.v, y and zero`. Full list:

`Counter({'z': 20230021, 'm': 18184241, 'm.d': 1123132, 'd': 1032908, 'wd': 667656, 'm.m': 468812, 's': 213008, 'm.s': 190193, 'm.q': 111030, 'b': 100118, 'q': 95519, 'm.b': 58849, 'n': 51576, 'voy': 36258, 'm.voy': 25983, 'w': 25506, 'v': 25045, 'm.v': 12886, 'm.n': 9851, 'y': 92, 'zero': 1})`

I imagine that the `m.` prefix stands for mobile and `voy` stands for wikivoyage and perhaps `zero` is to be ignored, but I still do not know what these stand for: `m, d, wd, w, y` **<= This is the crux of my question**. I suspect that I would enncounter other project codes in other files but that is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: `zero` is for zero-rated Wikipedia, a type of mobile view (which doesn't exist anymore).

Comment: Reported as [T249984](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T249984).

Comment: @Tgr, many thanks.

Comment: @Tgr, I made a small edit to the post. I never found a `k` in that file. Actually it looks like I never found a `wo` either. The string representation of the Conter object (essentually a str->int dict) is posted in its entirety. This is in reference to a comment in phabricator T249984 "The StackExchange question says they found occurrences of k but I haven't found any. d is the correct code for Wiktionary.". Just wanted to make my bug report less confusing.

Comment: Hi @Tgr, I saw that bug  T249984 as Closed, Resolved. I actually put that project on hold for now but when I do come back to it (and also for the benefit of others) - what is the resolution on this issue/summary? Toward the top of the bug report, I see 2 more open, related bugs - T251777 and T192474. It is hard to say what that means. I would appreciate another comment (or even an answer if it is warranted). Thanks.

Comment: Not sure there was a real resolution, other than the pointer to https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Learning_patterns/Tips_for_reading_project_codes_from_pageviews_data_files which seems pretty detailed.

Answer (score 1):

m, d, wd, w are all [shortcuts to Wikimedia sister sites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Interwiki_linking#Prefix_codes_for_linking_to_Wikimedia_sister_projects)